# HTTP response header for credentials

Tags: rest, http, cookies, server-response

Is there some HTTP response header intended for authentication/credentials-data except for `Set-Cookie`?

I am working on an HTTP API which transfer authentication tokens in cookies. I need to add support for a legacy system which supports all HTTP headers except `Set-Cookie` / `Cookie`.

When the user logs on, currently the server submits the token to the client in a `Set-Cookies` header. First I was thinking that I'll just make an implementation where I submit the token to the client in a custom header, like `MyOwnHeader: TheToken`, but then I read that this then may be cached by proxies and could lead to security issues. I read that most proxies skipped caching of `Set-Cookies`.

I could put the token in a HTTP response body, but then renewal of expired tokens become more complex. If it's included in a HTTP response header, it can be sent from the server to the client in any request when it's nearing expiration (just as is common for `Set-Cookies`).

After the client has logged on, it will submit the authentication token to the server in an `Authorization`-header. So my issue is related to submitting the token from the server to the client.

Comment: `Authorization` and `WWW-Authenticate`. Cookies aren't strictly meant for authentication data

Comment: Do look at this video, you should in general send tokens to the browser. https://youtu.be/lEnbi4KClVw